# Search an Object list for duplicate keys, and place string values into a string array

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

What I want to be able to do is search the searchValues list for duplicate itemId's, and when I find them, place the single string value into the string values array.

The SearchValue object:

```
public class SearchValue<TItemId>
{
    public TItemId ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

My test search values after init looks like this:

```
   searchValues[0]
        .ItemId == 16
        .Value == "2"
    searchValues[1]
        .ItemId == 16
        .Value == "3"
    searchValues[2]
        .ItemId == 15
        .Value == "6"
    searchValues[3]
        .ItemId == 15
        .Value == "3"
    searchValues[4]
        .ItemId == 5
        .Value == "Vertonghen"
```

I'd like my final result to look like this:

```
searchValues[0]
    .ItemId == 16
    .Values == "2,3"
searchValues[1]
    .ItemId == 15
    .Values == "6,3"
searchValues[2]
    .ItemId == 5
    .Value == "Vertonghen"
```

I'd really want to do this using LINQ. I've managed to create another List of SearchValue thusly:

```
List<SearchValue<Byte>> duplicateSearchItems = (from x in searchValues
                                 group x by x.ItemId into grps
                                 orderby grps.Key
                                 where grps.Count() > 1
                                 select grps).SelectMany(group => group).ToList();
```

...but getting the value into the values array is giving me trouble. Ideally if the LINQ could return a single list that contains the duplicate records transmogrified into the array with the non-duplicates intact would be best. Probably a nested query of some sort? I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do here...

Comment: I'm not much of an expert on LINQ but I think the main purpose of it is data retrieval, not so much manipulation. I think you might have to break this one down into multiple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out using LINQ.

```
// Get a new list of unique items to add our duplicated items to
List<SearchValue<Byte>> finalSearchItems = (from x in searchValues
                            group x by x.ItemId into grps
                            orderby grps.Key
                            where grps.Count() == 1
                            select grps).SelectMany(group => group).ToList();

byte[] duplicateIds = (from x in searchValues
             group x by x.ItemId into grps
             where grps.Count() > 1
             select grps.Key).ToArray();

// Smash the string 'Value' into 'Values[]'
foreach (byte id in duplicateIds)
{
    SearchValue<Byte> val = new SearchValue<byte>();
    val.ItemId = id;
    // Smash
    val.Values = (from s in searchValues
              where s.ItemId == id
              select s.Value).ToArray();
    finalSearchItems.Add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Dictionary

```
    Dictionary<int,string> d = new Dictionary<int,string>();
    foreach(var x in searchValues)
    {
        if(d.ContainsKey(x.ItemId))
           d[x.ItemId] = string.Format("{0},{1}",d[x.ItemId],x.Value);
        else
           d.Add(x.ItemId,x.Value);
    }
```

on the end simply iterate throug the Dictionary

```
    foreach(var entry in d)
    {
       ConsoleWriteline(entry.Key+" : "+entry.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq alone cannot be used to modify the original list or to modify the items in the list. However, you could do this to create a new list:

```
List<SearchValue<Byte>> results = 
    (from x in searchValues
     group x by x.ItemId into g
     select new SearchValue<Byte>()
     {
         ItemId = g.Key,
         Value = g.Value.First().Value,
         Values = g.Value.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray(),
     }
    .ToList();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
List<SearchValue<Byte>> results = searchValues
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId)
    .Select(g => new SearchValue<Byte>()
            {
                ItemId = g.Key,
                Value = g.Value.First().Value,
                Values = g.Value.Select(i => i.Value).ToArray(),
            })
   .ToList();
```

However, depending on your situation, an [`ILookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) may be more appropriate for you:

```
var results = searchValues.ToLookup(x => x.ItemId, x => x.Value);
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", results[16])); // 2, 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LINQ would provide you with the best solution here.  Similar to Nikola, I'd use a Dictionary.  If you aren't married to your SearchValue data type, you can avoid the second loop that just pushes your data back into your type.  A Dictionary> would work here.

```
            var searchValues = new List<SearchValue<int>>();
            var distinctItemIds = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

            foreach (var item in searchValues)
            {
                if (!distinctItemIds.ContainsKey(item.ItemId))
                {
                    distinctItemIds.Add(item.ItemId, new List<string>());
                }

                // Add the value
                distinctItemIds[item.ItemId].Add(item.Value);
            }

            // Put values back into your data object
            var finishedValues = new List<SearchValue<int>>();

            foreach (var keyValuePair in distinctItemIds)
            {
                finishedValues.Add(new SearchValue<int>()
                {
                    ItemId = keyValuePair.Key,
                    Values = keyValuePair.Value.ToArray()
                });
            }
```

Comment: I had considered this when I was starting up but thought that there would be a better way to do it using LINQ. It ended up being the best answer for what I was trying to do. I had to rejigger it a bit to add in some other things that would have complicated the original question. Thanks for all the help!